# Convert a D3 selection into a Jquery selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, d3.js

I have a D3 selection

```
let s = d3.select("#my-div")
```

that I would like to transform into a Jquery selection. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const d3Selection = d3.select("#my-div");    
const jQuerySelection = $(d3Selection.node());
```